# Dialog crashing the app

Tags: android, button, dialog

Ok just to know,I copy-pasted the code from the android website,so I don't think there is something wrong.

The problem is that when I press the button it crashes.And it crashes from the dialog code,because I don't have anything else there.

The code is:

MainDialog.xml:

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
          <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />
          <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />

          </LinearLayout>
```

And on the case that button1 is pressed:

```
                    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);    
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `Activity` context and add a call to `dialog.show();`:

```
    Context mContext = this; //Assumes you are calling this from within an activity
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);    
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: ok now it's there.However it crashes! I'll put the log in the first post.

Comment: You need to use the `Activity` context instead of `getApplicationContext()`. If you are running this all from within an activity, you can call `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);`