# can i put a dialog in a spinner item?

Tags: dialog, android-spinner

I'm new in the android world but I got experience in java.

Im trying to show a dialog when I select an especific item in my spinner but, when I do it, my application has stopped.

I have 1 fragment and 1 class for the listener, instantiate an object from the fragment in the listener and try to call the dialog.

The code is somthing like this:

```
    //Instantiate of class Guardar extends SherlockFragment.
Guardar controlador = new Guardar();

public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

String addSM = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

if (addSM == “Anyadir”){

// custom dialog
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(controlador.context);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_afegirsuper);
 dialog.setTitle(“Title…”);

// set the custom dialog components – text, image and button
  TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
  text.setText(“Android custom dialog example!”);

  Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
 // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
 dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
             dialog.dismiss();
       }
 });

 dialog.show();
 }
}
```

Is this possible to implement? another similar idea?

thanks a lot for any solution

Comment: Try to simplify it too it works. And it would be good if you remove all project specific code in your post( simplify the code ). It will be easier to get an answer then.

Comment: You maybe can look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7956860/1083313